# How do I remap Home Button key with Escape key on Apple keyboard?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I bought a bluetooth keyboard for $13, and it's pretty good except instead of the Esc key, there's a little square and it opens up Internet Explorer when it's pressed! I've tried 3 key remapping programs, and NONE worked, they either say that the key is not supported or it's disabled... I have no idea what to do, I am a gamer so the Esc key is crucial for me.

This is a picture of it:

[image: Keyboard]

On KeyTweak, it wouldn't even fetch the key in KeyMapper it would just open a new browser window. I've tried pressing Function and that Esc button, control and the escape button, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Here is how I solved:

- download and install autohotkey
- create an `.ahk` file with this content:

  ```
  Browser_Home::Esc
  ```
- save & run it

Comment: Haven't tried this but seems like a possible way to get this working!

Comment: yes this works!

Answer (score 1):

I bought one of these too. They are designed to be an iPad keyboard and where the escape should be is a home button, but if you press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> it will work as Escape key.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up remapping the Caps Lock key with the Esc key since nothing was recognizing that Home button key.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on keybaord and before typing press Fn + Q at same time to set keyboard in iOS mode.
( Fn + E = Windows mode )
( Fn + W = Android mode )
( Above works on my Arteck HB030B keyboard )

Comment: That works on keyboard where there are markings on the letter keys noted for the different OS modes, with a layout that looks like: https://www.pcworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/arteck-hb030b-wireless-bluetooth-keyboard-primary-100783366-orig.jpg?quality=50&strip=all

Answer (score 0):

On a mac you can fix this with Karabiner, you just need to go to simple modifications and choose to remap `ac_home` to `escape` or whatever key you prefer.

Saved me having to buy a new keyboard!