# In Karabiner, how can remap a special non-Escape key?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I got an external Bluetooth keyboard where the Escape key (<kbd>esc</kbd>) is missing, very similar to this post: [How do I remap Home Button key with Escape key on Apple keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/879539/how-do-i-remap-home-button-key-with-escape-key-on-apple-keyboard#1289878)

In reality, an the escape command is issued by pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. In AutoHotkey, the key code seems to be `Browser_Home`

I would like to  get that key to issue an ESC command without pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> on macOS. Preferably using Karabiner. But I can't find a key code for this key.